# How to write floating value on LCD?

Tags: c, embedded

I am calculating body mass ratio, which is floating value like 862.145, 56.21,664.008
this value I want to put on 16x2 lcd
I am using PIC18F4550 with MPLAB IDE v8.83

here is my code

```
float BMR_Male(unsigned char Age,unsigned int Weight,unsigned int Height)
{
    float BmrForMale = 0,term1=0,term2=0,term3=0;
    int intValue = 0,anotherIntValue = 0;
    float diffValue = 0;
    char str1[20],str2[20];
    unsigned age1 = Age;
    unsigned int Weight1 = Weight;
    unsigned int Height1 = Height;
    term1 = 13.75 * Weight;
    intValue = (int)term1;
    diffValue = term1 - (float)intValue;
    anotherIntValue = (int)(diffValue * 1000.0);
    sprintf(str1, (const far rom char*)"%s", intValue);
    sprintf(str2, (const far rom char*)"%s", anotherIntValue);
    for(z=0;z!='\0';z++)
    {
        LCD_write(str1[z]);    
        myMsDelay(5);
    }
    LCD_write('.');
    myMsDelay(5);
    for(z=0;z!='\0';z++)
    {
        LCD_write(str2[z]);    
        myMsDelay(5);
    }
//  term2 = 5 + Height1;
//  term3 = 6.76 * age1;
//  BmrForMale = (term1)+(term2)-(term3)+66;
    return BmrForMale ;
}
```

here i have displayed only one term...
term2 and term3 is commented for simplicity..

here i am getting only '.' on lcd .. not str1 and str2

Comment: `for(z=0;z!='\0';z++)`. That doesn't look right. The body of the loop will never execute as the for condition is never true. `z` is initialised to 0 so `z!='\0'` is always false.

Answer (score 2):

There is absolutely no reason to use float in this case. Instead of writing things like `13.75` in the code, you can as well write `1375`. Try to restrict calculations to 8 and 16 bit integers. And when all calculations are done, print the decimal comma wherever you want it.

The difference is that your PIC18 compiler will have to barf out an *extremely slow and memory consuming* program if you use floating point numbers. You are not programming a PC! You don't have a FPU and we're talking about what might very well be the slowest CPU in the world still in production here...

You *only* need to use floating point numbers if your program is doing things like trigonometry, signal processing, advanced math etc etc. In which case you picked the completely wrong MCU.

Similarly, your program will also turn extremely slow and memory consuming if you use the printf family of functions. sprintf will probably kill every single resource available in your PIC. In this case, simply roll out your own integer to string conversion routine. It is trivial and there is plenty of code for such available on SO.

Given that you only have a few kb of RAM available, your present code most likely has stack overflow and has probably consumed all available RAM with this function alone.

Comment: Downvoter care to explain? Someone has to point out to the OP that their project is going horribly wrong and that the current code is a ticking bomb. If their boss is an experienced programmer, their job might be at stake here. Pretending that this code is perfectly fine and that it is sane practice to use stdio and floating point on a restricted 8 bit PIC isn't doing neither the OP nor future readers a favour.

Comment: I am sorry for you that some naive desktop/server programmer saw fit to downvote your post, which exhibits a clear mastery of embedded programming techniques related to performing fractional number computations using integer variables, something that will make the difference in an embedded system between "product successful" and "product sucks".

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you're using wrong format specifier. Change

```
sprintf(str1, (const far rom char*)"%s", intValue);
sprintf(str2, (const far rom char*)"%s", anotherIntValue);
```

to

```
sprintf(str1, "%d", intValue);
sprintf(str2, "%d", anotherIntValue);
```

as, `intValue` and `anotherIntValue` are of type `int` which needs `%d` format specifier.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
sprintf(str1, (const far rom char*)"%s", intValue);
sprintf(str2, (const far rom char*)"%s", anotherIntValue);
```

To

```
sprintf(str1, "%d", intValue);
sprintf(str2, "%d", anotherIntValue);
```

But you can simply use

```
snprintf(str1, 20, "%f", term1);
z=0;
while(str1[z++]!= '\0')
{
    LCD_write(str1[z]);    
    myMsDelay(5);
}
```

or

```
int strlen = snprintf(str1, 20, "%f", term1);
for (z=0; z<strlen; z++)
{
    LCD_write(str1[z]);    
    myMsDelay(5);
}
```

The only thing to check is if the `'.'` char has the same code in your LCD. If not check and change it to the correct value before sending to LCD through `LCD_write()`.

Comment: I fear the MCC18 compiler which ships with MPLAB 8 scrimps on floating-point support for `printf`. Embedded compilers frequently have a switch to disable advanced (read: ROM hungry) `printf` formatting options but last time I checked this particular one didn't.

Comment: @doynax Yes, sure. printf floating point support could be memory eater on a 32 KB flash micro. AFAIK C18 doesn't support float on printf, but hitech compiler has support to %f on printf. Anyway it was a suggestion, I don't know OP specific app.